# C++ 6.0 code ignored after compile (Date Time calculator code)

Tags: c++, windows-10, visual-c++-6

This project I'm working on is forcing me to use Visual C++-6.0 and it seems like everytime I compile this code it causes errors in not only this segment of code but elsewhere that is unrelated to this portion.

Right now I am trying to calculate an expiration date that is 15 months from the date that would be given.

I've tried researching if this is a common issue after windows updates. I know 6.0 has been unsupported and phased out but its a "requirement" for this program. I swore it was working 2 months ago and since that point about 30 patches have been deployed to my Windows 10 device.

Currently in this snippit of code the date that is passed into the code is carried through unaltered. For example: Nov-01-2019 should become Feb-01-2021

```
    void CalculateDates(int numIndex)
{
        int tDay = 0, tMonth = 0, tYear = 0, exp_Months = 15;
        char sTemp1[4], sTemp2[4], sTemp3[4], sTemp4[4], sDay[4], sYear[4], *p;

        p = Database[numIndexCount].sIdentifier;
        strncpy(Database[numIndexCount].sPreparedBy, Database[numIndexCount].sIdentifier, 3);
        Database[numIndexCount].sPreparedBy[3] = 0;
        strncpy(sTemp1, p + 3, 2);
        sTemp1[2] = 0;
        strncpy(sTemp2, p + 5, 2);
        sTemp2[2] = 0;
        strncpy(sTemp3, p + 7, 2);
        sTemp3[2] = 0;

        strcpy(sTemp4, "20");
        SetDateMonth(sTemp1);

        sprintf(Database[numIndex].sPreparedDate, "%s-%s-%s%s", sTemp2, sMonth1, sTemp4, sTemp3);

        tDay = atoi(sTemp2);
        tMonth = atoi(sTemp1);
        tYear = atoi(sTemp3);

        if (tMonth <= 9) {
                if (tMonth == 9) {
                        tMonth = 12;
                        tYear++;

                //      cout << "Is the month printing right? ";
                //      cout<<tMonth;
                //      cout << "\n";

                }
                else {

                        tMonth = (tMonth + exp_Months) % 12;
                        tYear++;

                        //cout << "Is the month printing right? ";
                        //cout<<tMonth;
                        //cout << "\n";

                }

        }




        if (tMonth == 4 || tMonth == 6 || tMonth == 9 || tMonth == 11) {
        //              cout << "This is reached";
        //              cout << "\n";
        //              cout << "The day value is: ";
        //              cout << tDay;
        //              cout << "\n";
                if (tDay == 31)
                {
                        tDay = 30;
                }
        }

        if (tDay >= 29 && tMonth == 2 && tYear % 4 == 0) {
                if (tYear % 100 != 0) {
                        tDay = 29;
                }
                else if (tYear % 100 == 0 && tYear % 400 == 0) {
                        tDay = 29;
                }
        }


        else if (tYear % 4 != 0 && tMonth == 2) {
                tDay = 28;
        }
                sprintf(sTemp1, "%i", tMonth);
                if (tDay < 10) sprintf(sDay, "0%i", tDay);
                else sprintf(sDay, "%i", tDay);
                if (tYear < 10) sprintf(sYear, "0%i", tYear);
                else sprintf(sYear, "%i", tYear);


                SetDateMonth(sTemp1);

                sprintf(Database[numIndex].sUseByDate, "%s-%s-%s%s", sDay, sMonth1, sTemp4, sYear);
                sprintf(sUseByDate, "%s-%s-%s%s", sDay, sMonth1, sTemp4, sYear);


        }
```

End results for the above for today were Nov-01-19 but should have been Feb-01-19

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: I appreciate the advice, the debugger that was being used is also plagued with a compatibility bug that crashes after the necessary breakpoints were reached. For that debugger it is a known issue since it was designed for Visual C++ 6. Maybe I will try to research others that are compatible with this version of C++ though.

Comment: You don't need to actually use a debugger.  Print out the data after each operation to make sure it is what you expect.  If it isn't then you'll at least know where to start looking.

Comment: I've taken this code outside of the bulk program and have done just that and it actually works as expected. When compiled with the rest of the programs code that's when disaster strikes.

Comment: I should also mention that the commented out portions of the code were the original attempts of debugging that got me through to this point. The program was working fine up until yesterday. It had not been touched in a month so there is a chance the environment is the issue.